# Magento2 add custom values in collection->setOrder

Tags: collections, magento2

I need to add some custom values in setOrder() of a collection, but it is not working.

```
$collection->setOrder("((lat - ".$lat.")*(lat - ".$lat.")) + ((lng - ".$lng.")*(lng - ".$lng."))", 'ASC');
```

The final part of my collection query like this:

```
ORDER BY ((lat - -34.9226513)*(lat - -34.9226513)) + ((lng - 138.6094486)*(lng - 138.6094486)) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to get rid of the minus signs in the `$lat` and `$lng` variables so you can concatenate them properly.

Something like this (untested).

```
$latString = '(lat'. (($lat >= 0) ? '-' : '+').abs($lat).')';
$lngString = '(lng'. (($lng >= 0) ? '-' : '+').abs($lng).')';
$collection->setOrder($latString.'*'.$latString.'+'.$lngString.'*'.$lngString, 'ASC');
```